# XCode 7 beta 2 String is not convertible to StringLiteralConvertible

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, swift2

I was doing a playground to check swift 2.0 and this happens:
[image: XCode error]

I do not know if im missing something, or is this normal or what? Thanks.
In swift 1.2 is working as expected XCode 6.3.
EDIT: Code

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play


import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"

let languageType: String = "Swift"

var version = 1.0 //infered
let introduced = 2014 //infered
let isAwesome = true //infered
let π = 3.1415927
let  = "dogcow"

let someString = "I appear to be a string"

let pathComponent = "~/Documents/Swift".pathComponents

var s = String("bla vla nla")

for character in "catDog" {

    print(character)
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code, not a screen shot.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the API for String has changed in Swift 2, to accomplish what it looks like you are trying to do, you would instead use `for character in "catDog".characters {...}`

an excellent reference is Nate Cook's [swiftdoc.org](http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/type/String/)

Comment: Thanks that was it, why do they change String? I will check the book.

Comment: maybe better to watch the WWDC 15 videos if you're looking for an explanation as to "why"  :)  many things changed, not just String, and I think it was all done as part of their move towards a "protocol oriented programming" language (see esp. this video -> https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408)